# How to automatic control uwsgi log size

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

When my service run in uwsgi for a long time, the log file size grows very large. I want to find a way to automatic control the log size. For example, service in supervisor will cut into several pieces and it reserve the last 10 pieces.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you need [log-maxsize](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#log-maxsize)

```
[uwsgi]
;...
;...
log-maxsize = 2048
```

Comment: In what units is it? Bytes?

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to setup logrotate to keep backups for files (which you can have it compress the rotated log).
http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html